# How to prove $p(f(f(X)))$ or $AX:p(f(X)) \implies p(f(f(X))))$, given that $AX:(p(X) \implies p(f(X)))$

Tags: logic, induction, predicate-logic

I have the following:

Objects: $a$

Functions: $f$

Now, the following are the premises:

Premises:

$p(a)$

$AX:(p(X) \implies p(f(X)))$

In other words,

$p(a)$

$\forall X.(p(X) \implies p(f(X)))$

Now, how can I show that $p(f(f(X)))$ holds (the goal statement)? If this is not possible, is there a way to prove $AX:(p(f(X))\implies p(f(f(X))))$? I am also able to use this intermediate conclusion from this subproof for my full proof.

I am trying to solve this as an intermediate step, but since I am new to using induction from a logic perspective (and using second order logic), I am not sure how to proceed. This is an intermediate step in a tree induction proof, and all things such as propositional logic and relational logic steps such as And/Or/Negation/Implication/Biconditional Introduction/Elimination are defined, and Assumptions are given (which can be closed out by Implication Intros), as well as quantifier logic such as Universal/Existential Introduction/Elimination.

For this intermediate step, I'm not sure if I even need to apply any type of induction, as tree induction will not allow linear induction as far as the Fitch system proof I am using goes (due to there not being a successor in a linear sense).

Comment: You can prove $p(f(f(a))$, but certainly not $p(f(f(X))$

Comment: I should say, given the Object universe only consists of $a$, and using Universal introduction, wouldn't it be possible to prove $AX: p(f(f(X)))$? Since if $p(f(f(a)))$ is provable, this means $\forall x.(p(f(f(X))))$ since the Object universe only consists of $a$, and the function universe only consists of $f$.

Comment: You would need to add an axiom like $\forall X. X = a$ to guarantee that every model consists of a single object.

Comment: For the case above, the only Object in the object universe is $a$, and in the Function universe is $f$. So doesn't this mean that by definition we can prove $AX: (p(f(f(X))))$? Or, alternatively, can I prove that $AX: (p(f(X)) \implies p(f(f(X))))$?

Comment: You have to distinguish between a theory and a model of a theory. You say your model as only one element, this is equivalent to adding a hypothesis to your theory like I mentioned above. Given that $\forall X.p(X)\implies p(f(X))$, of course you can prove $\forall X.p(f(X))\implies p(f(f(X)))$.

Comment: ah ok - that means that the Object universe and Function universe given acts as a Premise/Hypothesis and other results need to be proved. I understand that now.

However, $\forall X.(p(X) \implies p(f(X)))$, then how would it be possible to prove $\forall X.(p(f(X)) \implies p(f(f(X))))$? I am having trouble in proving this part and I am not sure how to proceed given the above Premises. So far, I have assumed a hypothesis  $p([c])$, Universal Elimination on $\forall X.(p(X) \implies p(f(X)))$ to get $p([c]) \implies p(f([c]))$, and Implication Elimination to obtain $p(f([c]))$.

Comment: From there on, I am not sure how to proceed in order to obtain the desired result, as an Implication Introduction would need to be performed in order to close the Assumption $p([c])$ mentioned in the prior comment. This would yield $p([c]) \implies p(f([c]))$, which is not really helpful (since this is essentially the same result prior to Universal Introduction, which is already a premise).

Comment: Just instantiate $X$ to $f(X)$ instead of $c$

Comment: unfortunately, in my current Fitch system, I don't have a way to instantiate a placeholder like $[c]$ with a free variable or an object - only the relational introduction/elimination and propositional introduction/elimination methods as well as induction. I am not quite sure how to proceed and have been stuck for a while - I can include an image as well.